# How to make square imageButton?

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there a file xml in the android studio:

```
    <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal"> 

<imageButton 
android:id="@+id/imageButton1" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
android:scaleType="fitXY" /> 

<imageButton 
android:id="@+id/imageButton2" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
android:scaleType="fitXY" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

I need to have the full width of 2 square buttons, how can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your custom view here by Extending `ImageButton` View.In `onMeasure()`, you can set the height of the `ImageButton` equal to its width. you can use this class in your XML as well.

Here is the snippet:-

```
public class SquareImageButton extends ImageButton {


    public SquareImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width=getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width,width);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell me please, how can I find out in this class the id of the ImageButton?

Comment: All found: getId()

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Programmatically get the `width` of the `display`.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

**2.** Finally, use this `width` value to make `Square Button` by setting its new `LayoutParams(width, width).`

```
ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
ImageButton imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, width);
imageButton1.setLayoutParams(params);
imageButton2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**3.** Use `ScrollView` as a container of your `LinearLayout` to make your layout `scroll-able` to show both button on UI and update `XML` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

FYI, `ImageButton1` is `RED` colored and `ImageButton2` is `BLUE` colored. Both are in `Square` shape.

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you!! I used the first option

Comment: If my answer helps and seems useful then please mark it as right answer. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Tenday previously you marked my answer as right answer and you removed it later. May i know the actual reason?

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly you'll need a square image to put into the imageButton.  Then you'll set AdjustViewBounds to true. and then set the scaletype to FitXY. I use linear layouts and use the weights and views to adjust the size and position.  Good for scaling and the imageButton will square. This is under my ImageButton in the xml:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Thank you! You answered my other question, leave it there, mark it as correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956756/how-work-tablelayout-with-imagebutton?noredirect=1#comment74944806_43956756