# How work TableLayout with imageButton?

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton, tablelayout, tablerow

I have Table:

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:background="#111111"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/w"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="#111111"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="#111111"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:background="#111111"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="#111111"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="#111111"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:background="#111111"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="#111111"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="#111111"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Initially, everything looks good, but when I insert a picture, it immediately deforms, adjusting to the image, as in the screenshot. Tell me how to solve this problem?
[good table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgMFK.png) and
[bad table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xyDS.png)

Comment: It happens because of the image's different sizes, You have to resize images using bitmap or any library. I hope that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the ImageButtons, set AdjustViewBounds to true. and then set the scaletype to FitXY. I use weights and views to adjust the size and position. For an ImageButton in a TableRow, the layout_width will have to be set to 0 for the weights to work. It scales very well. This should be under an ImageButton in an xml:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```